# Mongoose/Mongo faster to have separate collections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Currently I have a schema USERS with a sub doc VIEWED
As a 'user' views other users, their ID gets logged in the viewers sub doc

So when viewing, technically this gets all the users, then filters that through all the viewed users [for any given user]. So you get a list of unique/fresh users.

My method is currently fetching the list of users - Query 1
Then its fetching the list of viewed users (for a given user) - Query 2
Then using array.filter function to get a list of new users.
(using async parallel for those queries)

Question is, would it be faster to just have a separate document/collection that stores a list of viewed users for any given user. e.g:

```
{
  userID: 1002,
  viewedID: 9112
},
{
  userID: 1002,
  viewedID: 9222
},
{
  userID: 1002,
  viewedID: 9332
}
```

Is it possible for me to some how do a query that gets me a fresh list of users, so i don't have to do the computation myself. i.e let mongo do all the work.

edit, adding code to make it more clear

```
var ViewedSchema = new Schema({
    coupleId: {type: Number, required: true}
});


var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name  : { type: String, trim: true, required: true}
  , partnerId  : { type: Number}
  , viewed  : [ViewedSchema] 
});
```

code to view partners/users that have not been viewed before

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        //gets all the users/partners
        User.find({}, function(err, users) {
            var allPartners = [];
            users.forEach(function(user){
                if(allPartners.indexOf(user.partnerId) == -1) {
                    allPartners.push(user.partnerId);
                }
            });
            callback(null, allPartners);
        }); 
    },

    function(callback) {
        //gets all the users/partners i have already viewed
        var votedPartners = [];         
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            user.viewed.forEach(function(user){
                votedPartners.push(user.coupleId);
            });

            callback(null, votedPartners);
        }); 
    }
], 
    function(err, result) {
        //gets the differences between the 2 arrays
        function exists(element) {
            return (result[1].indexOf(element) == -1);
        }   

        var showPartners = result[0].filter(exists);

        User.find({partnerId: showPartners[0]}, function(err, user){
            var json  = {objects: user};    
            res.render('index', json);
        });         
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by fresh or new users, exactly, but have you loked at the distinct() command? You can use it to get all the unique viewed user IDs for all the users in the collection, which is what it sounds like you want to do.  See
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

From the documentation:
Return an array of the distinct values of the field sku in the subdocument item from all documents in the orders collection:
db.orders.distinct( 'item.sku' )

If you give an example of your current document schema, I could try to write the exact query for you.

Edit: You can use $nin to find the userIds that are not in a given list. Here is an example I set up in my local Mongo:

```
> db.dating.insert({"userId":100,"viewedId":["200","201"]})

> db.dating.findOne()

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5398d81799b228e88aef2441"),
        "userId" : 100,
        "viewedId" : [
                "200",
                "201"
        ]
}

> db.dating.insert({"userId":200,"viewedId":[""]})
> db.dating.insert({"userId":201,"viewedId":[""]})
> db.dating.insert({"userId":202,"viewedId":[""]})
> db.dating.insert({"userId":203,"viewedId":[""]})
> db.dating.insert({"userId":204,"viewedId":[""]})
> db.dating.insert({"userId":205,"viewedId":[""]})

> db.dating.find({"userId":{$nin: [200,201]}})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5398d81799b228e88aef2441"), "userId" : 100, "viewedId" : [ "
200", "201" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5398d84099b228e88aef2444"), "userId" : 202, "viewedId" : [ "
" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5398d84799b228e88aef2445"), "userId" : 203, "viewedId" : [ "
" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5398d85699b228e88aef2446"), "userId" : 204, "viewedId" : [ "
" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5398d85c99b228e88aef2447"), "userId" : 205, "viewedId" : [ "
" ] }
```

Comment: i don't quite understand distinct, i dont think i've described myself correctly.

Consider a dating app, that shows YOU females, once you've viewed a female, the app wont show you her again. So essentially the database is logging all the females you've viewed. 

So it needs to fetch all the females in the database, then it fetches all the females you've viewed, and then just show you the difference i.e ones that you have not viewed yet [fresh, lol]

Comment: Updated to illustrate using $nin